# Python3.8 Pip Distutils.cmd Not Found

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I was trying to have a virtualenv set up where it is at python 3.8 while my system is at a more recent version.

I have figured out how to create the venv but now when I try to install packages like mediapipe and opencv-python and everything else I get an error saying:  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'`. I have tried `sudo apt-get install python-distutils` and `sudo apt-get install python-apt` but they are all up to date and do nothing.

I am on Debian Bullseye (the raspberry pi one though)

Thanks

(P.S Sorry if this is a duplicate but nothing else worked)

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/issues/124 Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=%22No+module+named+distutils.cmd%22

Comment: python-distutils is "old python2" . A python3 package is `python3-distutils`

Answer (score 13):

I got the same issue, what resolved it was to install `distutils` for `pythonV.v` specfically with

```
sudo apt install pythonV.v-distutils
```

In mycase V.v == 3.8

Answer (score 2):

Dears,

In my case I used the command below to fix my issue:

```
sudo apt install python3-distutils
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install python3-distutils
亲测可以

Comment: How is this different from [@Mohamed-Elaragy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76214720/3025856) from a few months ago? The only difference are some Chinese (Simplified) characters which appear to translate to "Can be tested personally". This appears to simply be validating an existing answer, not providing a new answer?