# Install packages for Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, pip, python-3.9

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, after the update, the default python changed to Python  3.10. However, most of the libraries I'm currently using are only available on 3.9.

when I try to install packages by

`pip install mypackage`

it is by default installed for python 3.10,  V3.9 by

```
python3.9 -m pip install mypackage
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

It is essential that I should be able to install these modules for Python3.9. I tried to achieve the same by installing a Virtual environment using Pycharm and even inside this VE I'm getting this 'distutil' error. How can we fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977089/7976758 Try `sudo apt install python3.9-distutils` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22No+module+named+distutils.cmd%22

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also had to add the deadsnakes ppa.