# Can't use pip-review to update packages and keep getting : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_msi'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, distutils

I'm currently trying to use a convenient way to update my packages in my venv. I'm using for a while pip-review whith no problems.

Currently using conda and Python 3.9.7

Now i'm using the classic `pip-review --auto` or `pip-review --interactive` i can't resolve the following problem.

The full traceback is :

```
python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\silvagnoli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9qlus9r0\pycurl_d735f7d8d97b40b0a041f12dfd001811\setup.py", line 954, in <module>
          setup_args['cmdclass'] = {'bdist_msi': get_bdist_msi_version_hack()}
        File "C:\Users\silvagnoli\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9qlus9r0\pycurl_d735f7d8d97b40b0a041f12dfd001811\setup.py", line 594, in get_bdist_msi_version_hack
          from distutils.command.bdist_msi import bdist_msi
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_msi'
      [end of output]
```

already update pip / wheel / setuptools as it can provoke egg_info exit code: 1

I would appreciate any ideas on this, thanks.

Comment: does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977089/11716409